# How to add a custom domain to a Salesforce experience cloud site?

Tags: salesforce, force.com, salesforce-communities

I am trying to add a custom domain to my Salesforce experience cloud site. I have been trying to follow [these instructions](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_custom_domain.htm&type=5) but I don't see an option to add a domain when I go through setup. I have a partner developer edition org. Is there another way to do this? Or am I missing some necessary permissions? I am an admin in the org.

Answer (score 0):

https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000336819&type=1

> Custom domains are available in Professional, Enterprise, Performance,
> and Unlimited Editions

Ask your SF account manager or raise ticket with support but sounds like Dev edition is a no, even if it's the bigger, Partner version.